# Compound keys in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, compound-key

I want to make an entity that has an autogenerated primary key, but also a unique compound key made up of two other fields. How do I do this in JPA?
I want to do this because the primary key should be used as foreign key in another table and making it compound would not be good.

In the following snippet, I need the command and model to be unique. pk is of course the primary key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dm_action_plan")
public class ActionPlan {
    @Id
    private int pk;
    @Column(name = "command", nullable = false)
    private String command;
    @Column(name = "model", nullable = false)
    String model;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with using a compound key as a foreign key?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`@UniqueConstraint`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html) something like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dm_action_plan",
       uniqueConstraints={ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames= "command","model") } )
public class ActionPlan {
    @Id
    private int pk;

    @Column(name = "command", nullable = false)
    private String command;

    @Column(name = "model", nullable = false)
    String model;
}
```

This will allow your JPA implementation to generate the DDL for the unique constraint.

Comment: The correct form is like this:  
@Table(name = "dm_action_plan") @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"command", "model"})

Comment: homaxto: According to the EJB3.0 specification, Michel gave the right form.

Answer (score 1):

Use @GeneratedValue to indicate that the key will be generated and @UniqueConstraint to express unicity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dm_action_plan"
       uniqueConstraint = @UniqueConstraint({"command", "model"})
)
public class ActionPlan {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int pk;
    @Column(name = "command", nullable = false)
    private String command;
    @Column(name = "model", nullable = false)
    String model;
}
```

Comment: It will not create a compound constraint. It will create two constraints, each one for each column name that you annoted in @UniqueConstraint.

Comment: Then your JPA implementation is wrong. JPA2 specification, §11.1.49 columnNames is "An array of the column names that make up the
**constraint**" (constraint, not constraints).