# JPA: alternative keys via @UniqueConstraint a DDL feature only?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, unique-constraint

I'm basically referring to this:

[Compound keys in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90885/compound-keys-in-jpa)

Is the @UniqueConstraint annotation a DDL generation feature only, or more specifically, does it have any effect at runtime, e.g. SQL generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most JPA implementations will use it for DDL generation as you say, but at runtime will simply defer unique checking to the datastore (which will throw an exception on non uniqueness).